# Network is lost, can not connect to any site (LAN network, issue persists on 1 computer only and few day ago everything was fine)

Tags: networking

I am new to superuser, so forgive me if i make a mistake or two in posting this question.

The problem is related to the network, I had it a few days ago and now I can't open any site. It is cable Internet through LAN. Only one computer is having this problem in all LAN, and network item in taskbar seems just fine. Below I have posted some screenshots of the problematic computer (YUBCWS-25) configuration and one screenshot with the configuration of fine-working computer next to it (YUBCWS-24).

[ipconfig /all](https://imageshack.com/i/idCeAtAYp)
[ipconfig /all of working config beside](https://imageshack.com/i/exLyGWmyp)

for more screens please check folder under Hettrik username

I have already tried a lot of things, like setting IPv4 address (default gateway, DNS) both manually and automatically, trying ipconfig /release, using network cable from computer beside,... It seems the problem is of software nature, so I also disabled Windows firewall. The problem occurred in about time Sophos antivirus was installed, can it be a problem?

Thanks in advance, any help would be great.

Comment: Uninstall Sophos and see if it fixes it ?

Comment: Anti-virus programs install a network filter, so Sophos is definitely the prime suspect.

Answer (score 0):

As Lawrence suggested (try undoing any other changes), but even more comprehensive - Try System Restore to an earlier date, before the issue started.